# Android (4.4.3) BroadcastReceiver and HttpURLConnection make go down Internet Connection

Tags: android, exception, httpurlconnection

I'm new on Android Programming,
andI'm writing an App (on **Android 4.4.3**) that checks the beacons that are around and call an internet url to have some information (in json).

So, i've simply created an AppCompatActivity with a **LocalBroadcastManager**

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(currentActivity).registerReceiver(
            new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

                    Log.i("ActionTread", intent.getStringExtra(BeaconAutostartService.EXTRA_BEACON_ADDRESS));

                    URL url = null;
                    JSONArray actions = null;
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                    try {

                        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.9/milkrun/public/beacon/"+intent.getStringExtra(BeaconAutostartService.EXTRA_BEACON_ADDRESS));

                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        Log.i(TAG, "Open connection... " + url.toString());
                        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                        urlConnection.connect();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response code... " + Integer.toString(status));

                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        String response = readStream(in);


                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        String error = json.getString("error");
                        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR " + error);

                        JSONObject beacon = json.getJSONObject("beacon");
                        Log.i(TAG, "COLOR " + beacon.getString("color"));
                        Log.i(TAG, "IMAGE " + beacon.getString("image"));


                        actions = json.getJSONArray("actions");
                        Log.i(TAG, "ACTIONS " + actions.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = actions.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.i(TAG, "ACTIONS " + Integer.toString(i) + " ID:" + obj.getString("id") + " DESCR: " + obj.getString("description"));
                        }

                        mBeaconActionAdapter = new BeaconActionAdapter(currentActivity, actions);
                        mListView.setAdapter(mBeaconActionAdapter);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"JSONException" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException" + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "IOException" + e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        if (urlConnection != null) {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new IntentFilter(BeaconAutostartService.ACTION_BEACON_BROADCAST)
    );
```

The problem is that when i reach

`urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

I've this error that ***"stop" the internet connection*** and i've to reconnect the smartphone to the router!

> 02-21 10:02:21.739 18640-18640/it.lmconsulting.milkrun I/ForTesting: Open connection... http://192.168.1.9/milkrun/public/beacon/A0:E6:F8:34:88:EE
>
> 02-21 10:02:24.752 18640-18640/it.lmconsulting.milkrun E/ForTesting: IOException failed to connect to /192.168.1.9 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

I've no firewall and the same code on an another smartphone with Android 6.0 works perfectly

Comment: Do not ask for a response code before you connect.

Comment: Even if I don't execute urlConnection.getInputStream(), I've the same problem

Comment: Of course. Well did you adapt the code as i suggested?

Comment: Now i execute only

            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.9/milkrun/public/beacon/"+beaconAddress);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.connect();

and i've the same error

Comment: Remove the connect() statement.

Comment: What is the ip of ths device?

Comment: `and call an internet url ` 192.168.. is not an internet ip,

Comment: `problem is that when i reach

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

I've this error that "stop" the internet connection and i've to reconnect the smartphone to the router!`. No not at that statement but later as the logline after that is still executed.

Comment: `make go down internet Connection` A lost wifi connection with your router has nothing to do with internet.

Comment: the url is correct (I don't know why has been missed "http" in copy/paste)
Even if I remove connect(I i receive the same error..

However I've tried to execute the code outside LocalBroadcastReceiver and run correctly.. 

so the problem is in LocalBroadcastReceiver + HttpUrlConnection ??